# Chat App when upload large file and insert text

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Problem is when upload large File and typing text ?

Insert in database ...

text is created before file .

that`s because file is large ..

How to make this ??

Comment: Hi Ramy, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is not clear. Are you trying to insert text and an image into a database? Perhaps you should explain the expected outcome of your code, and then describe the problem. It would help as well if you posted the **relevant** code in your script.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `CONCAT(textmessage,file text)` in insert statement

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Sir,  I thought the large file is a text file. Generally we store only the path for images.